# dnsmasq reads addn-hosts config but ignores it, falls back to system's /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, hosts-file, dnsmasq, networkmanager

I'm running `dnsmasq` installed as a `NetworkManager` plugin on Fedora 39 machine

My configs are:

1. `/etc/dnsmasql.conf` (default, nothing changed):

```
user=dnsmasq
group=dnsmasq
interface=lo
bind-interfaces
conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d,*.conf
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.rpmnew,.rpmsave,.rpmorig
```

2. `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/00-use-dnsmasq.conf`

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

3. `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/00-add-hosts.conf`

```
log-queries
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.d
address=/development/127.0.0.1
```

`/etc/hosts.d` is a directory with the hosts files, they include domains I want to "sinkhole", e.g.:

```
0.0.0.0 1.example.com
0.0.0.0 2.example.com
...
```

From logfiles I see that `dnsmasq` config is ok and my `addn-hosts` directory's hosts files are read:

```
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: chown of PID file /run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid failed: Operation not permitted
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: warning: no upstream servers configured
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: read /etc/hosts.d/private - 10 names
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53(via wlp2s0)
```

But these hosts file don't have any effect, domains from them are still resolved not to 0.0.0.0 as I'd expect, but to domains real external IP addresses.

On the other hand, when I add the same domains to the `/etc/hosts`, they are resolved to 0.0.0.0 as expected, though `no-hosts` option is explicitly used in the config file and passed as an option to dnsmasq daemon:

```
ps aux | grep dnsmasq

dnsmasq    61161  0.4  0.0 228096  4480 ?        S    16:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.0.1 --cache-size=400 --clear-on-reload --conf-file=/dev/null --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0 trust-ad
```

I know that some `dnsmasq` configs are ok, e.g. `address=/development/127.0.0.1` works as expected. But somehow, configs related to hosts files are ignored.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to the great advice from [this
answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1150714/291239).

TLDR; A DNS server from `dnsmasq` running on localhost doesn't
necessary mean it's used by the `NetworkManager`, even if the
`/etc/resolv.conf` says explicitly so; If your local machine is using
your router's DHCP server, you got DNS server settings from it too.

TIL; `dig` uses a DNS server from `/etc/resolv.conf` by default, even
if a connection managed by the `NetworkManager` uses DNS server
address obtained from the DHCP; hence the difference how `dig` and,
say, `curl` resolve the same hostname.

Troubleshooting:

1. Check, if my localhost DNS from `dnsmasq` is indeed working as expected:

```
# dig or nslookup a host from my addn-hosts's hosts file
$ dig 1.example.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
1.example.com.      0   IN  A   0.0.0.0
[...]
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
```

Hostname resolved to `0.0.0.0` (as stated by `addn-hosts` hosts file)
by the `127.0.0.1` (`dnsmasq` local DNS server) as expected.

Why then all the all the requests from `curl` or a browser to the same
hostname got resolved not though my local DNS from `dnsmasq`, but,
obviously, from another upstream DNS, despite `/etc/resolv.conf`
saying:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0 trust-ad
```

That mean something is overriding DNS settings. Must be `NetworkManager`

2. Check what `NetworkManager` is using as DNS:

```
$ nmcli device show | grep -i dns
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a02:8383:d:c::1000
IP6.DNS[2]:                             2a02:8383:d:c::1
```

Indeed, instead of what `/etc/resolv.conf` says, `NetworkManager` uses
my WiFi router's DNS addresses. This is because a WiFI connection on
my local machine uses router's `DHCP` settings.

3. Set upstream DNS servers in `dnsmasq`

Before fixing DNS used by the `NetworkManager`, we need to add some
upstream DNS that will be used once hosts files are checked. Here's
how my whole `dnsmasq` config looks like now:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/00-add-hosts.conf

# NB! When making changes, don't forget restart dnsmasq & NetworkManager.service:
# $ killall dnsmasq
# $ systemctl restart NetworkManager

# No need to read /etc/resolv.conf as it contains the localhost
# addresses of dnsmasq itself
no-resolv

# Upstream DNS servers
# My router, Google, CloudFlare
server=192.168.0.1
server=8.8.8.8
server=1.1.1.1

# Add debug logging
# $ journalctl --follow -u NetworkManager
log-queries

# Ignore /etc/hosts
no-hosts

# Add custom hosts files; 
# If path is a directory, all files from it are loaded
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.d
```

4. Fix DNS servers in `NetworkManager`'s connection settings:

Open up `nm-connection-editor` (or Settings -> WiFi -> Network you're
connected to Settings), then `IPv4`:

- Method -> Automatic (DHCP) addresses only
- DNS Server -> 127.0.0.1 (instead of automatic one)

then for `IPv6`:

- Method -> Automatic, DHCP only (watch out, it's different than for `IPv4`)

This corresponds to the changes in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YOUR-CONNECTION-NAME.nmconnection`:

```
[ipv4]
dns=127.0.0.1;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns=::1;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=dhcp
```

Now, restart the `dnsmasq` and the `NetworkManager`:

```
$ sudo killall dnsmasq
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

et voilà! `NetworkManager` uses localhost as a DNS server, all
requests from `curl` or a web browser get resolved using it, extra
hosts files from `dnsmasq`'s `addn-hosts` are respected:

```
$ nmcli device show | grep -i dns
IP4.DNS[1]:                             127.0.0.1
IP6.DNS[1]:                             ::1
```

```
$ curl -v 1.example.com
* processing: 1.example.com
*   Trying 0.0.0.0:80...
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying [2604:a880:400:d0::2082:1001]:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2604:a880:400:d0::2082:1001: Network is unreachable
* Failed to connect to lobste.rs port 80 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
```